# Using Nikkor 50mm f/1.2 on Sony a7r (with Metabones adapter)

Tags: nikon, sony, adapter

So here it is: I am considering getting a good old manual nikkor 50mm f/1.2
And I wonder if there could be any problems using it on my sony a7r?

Will it work? Do I lose in quality or anything?

PS: The adapter I use has no optical elements in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work perfectly in my experience and I use a cheaper $30 adapter. There are a few things to remember:

1. Generally AI can be found for less than the AI-S and the -S won't function anyways (until there's electronic adapters). The downside of course is if you do upgrade to an electronic adapter you might want the -S
2. Aperture information will not be in the metadata of your images
3. Like there is no electronics also means more difficult to remote tether

As far as quality goes it is impeccable. I shoot almost exclusively with old manual lenses including Nikkor and its brilliant. I get no real difference in quality than I did when I was on an actual Nikon body but all of the resolution, sensor, and EVF goodness.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work, but obviously as a manual only lens. There shouldn't be any notable loss in quality, however there may be some in the corners depending on the combo's precision.